# Ember js: Update single li instead of enitre ul

Tags: ember.js

I have one page which displays list of similar item using html ul and li combination. This list should get update in regular interval when ever any of li item(value) changes at back-end. This is happening. My issue is I just want to update/redraw the particular list which was updated not the entire html ul (all list item). I am using #each in my template. Is there any way to achieve this? Please guide on this.

Comment: please provide some code

Answer (score 0):

If you´re relying on each the hole list is updated when the input changes, you could build a list of components where the component represents each item

```
{{#each listItems as |item|}}
   {{item-component content=item}}
{{/each}}
```

So listItems would only update if there´re new items (.property('input.[]')) and the component would update the content of the item itself if changed